# Hide a delivery option (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, delivery

We are using Magento 2 and have international delivery available on our site.

However lets say, the customer wants delivery to Australia, the UK price is still shown present to the customer.

How do I hide a delivery option, so the customer can not see the UK delivery price when selecting a different country.

Thanks

Comment: please attach screenshot

Comment: Which Shipping method do you have use?

Comment: HI All, Managed to sort it, the resolve was adding a rule

Comment: which type of rule please add your answer